# Allocation and Deallocation of objects on different threads causing memory leaks.

Tags: ios5, thread-safety, twrequest

I am using TWRequest to call out to Twitter each time i make a request i get a memory leak inside instruments like so. on [request performRequestWithHandler:]
[image: leaking thread]

I am tracing out the allocation and deallocation of the class that contains the request. It is being allocated on the main thread (1) but is being deallocated on another thread for example thread 6 ( the thread is arbitrary ). My question is could this be the cause of the memory leaks I am seeing?